# Boost solr results based on a field value

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am new to solr and trying to fetch results from it. I want results which exactly matches my phrase ex: "test test1 test2" and any document which has any of these keywords, so kind of union of exact match and partial matches.

I am pretty much achieving it using dismax. Now i want the results to be sorted/boosted on the basis of some field value eg: cat:A, then cat:B then cat:C also I want this sorting to be applied first on exactly matched result then partial matched results.

Indexed data is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "name": "test test1 test2 Z",
    "price": 12.9,
    "cat": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "name": "test test1 test2 X",
    "price": 91.5,
    "cat": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "test test1 test2 R",
    "price": 45.5,
    "cat": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": "004",
    "name": "test test1 test2 C",
    "price": 78.67,
    "cat": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": "005",
    "name": "data",
    "price": 91.5,
    "cat": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "008",
    "name": "test test1 test2 D",
    "price": 45.09,
    "cat": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "009",
    "name": "test test1 test2 B",
    "price": 34.09,
    "cat": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": "010",
    "name": "test test1 test2 A",
    "price": 39.19,
    "cat": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": "011",
    "name": "test this data",
    "price": 89.19,
    "cat": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": "012",
    "name": "this is my data",
    "price": 89.19,
    "cat": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": "013",
    "name": "test1 is this data title",
    "price": 89.19,
    "cat": "A"
  }
]
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.